# how to send in js file data to header.phtml file when click a link in magento?

Tags: javascript, magento

My js file:

```
$j('.language_eng').click(function(){
       var lan = "eng";


    $j.ajax({
       url:"<?php echo $this->getUrl('app/design/fontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml') ?>",
       type:'POST',
       data:{language:lan},
       success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
       }
      });

   });
```

My header.phtml file:

```
<?php $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));

                $language = $_POST['language'];
                echo $language;
                // set data
               $session->setData("language",$language);
                // get data
                $lang = $session->getData("language"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can't do it that way. You can't access phtml file via browser. Templates are only part of controller/layout/block structure.